# How to fix overlap issue in Google Visualization - Materials Line

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Looks like when the value for two different fields is the same, you can only see the most recent on on top.

Is there a way to account for the overlapping so that we can see each field that belongs to the value?

Example here -

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var userArray = [
    'x',
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
    'f',
    'g',
    'h',
    'i',
    'k'
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length ; i++) {
      data.addColumn('number', userArray[i]);
  }


  data.addRows([
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      ]);


  var options = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 563,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'item'
    },
    series: {
      1: {
        curveType: 'function'
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('ex2'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

The Fields for "b", "e", and "h" all have a "y" value of  "1", but only "h" is seen on the graph, a user who doesn't know this might not know that "b" and "e" also have a "y" value of "1", how can I account for this overlap?

http://jsfiddle.net/6hzc5wmt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to resolve this is to use the special `option` of `focusTarget: 'category'` [Google dev docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?csw=1#configuration-options)

However, there also looks to be a bug with this setting on the Materials version of the code ( a fiddle of the bug http://jsfiddle.net/6hzc5wmt/3/ **This isn't really a bug, it's a not-yet-implemented feature**). I had to use classic version Line Chart:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var userArray = [
    'x',
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
    'f',
    'g',
    'h',
    'i',
    'k'
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length ; i++) {
      data.addColumn('number', userArray[i]);
  }


  data.addRows([
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      ]);


  var options = {
    focusTarget: 'category',
    width: 1000,
    height: 563,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'item'
    },
    series: {
      1: {
        curveType: 'function'
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ex2'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hzc5wmt/1/